# How to set line color to orange, and specify line markers

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a situation where I have many lines that I am plotting in pyplot.

They are grouped by color, and within each color, I plot according to plot style--so the circles, dashes, etc.

My plot styling is:

```
plt.plot(x,y1,'b')
plt.plot(x,y2,'bs')
plt.plot(x,y3,'b--')
```

And then I repeat for various colors.  However, I am running into trouble with orange.  When I plot with orange, I get an error because pyplot wants to plot with circles instead of the color orange! Here is an example:

```
plt.plot(x,z1,'o')
plt.plot(x,z2,'os')
plt.plot(x,z3,'o--')
```

This fails because `'os'` is being parsed as two formatting instructions, rather than a color and the format: squares.

How do I work around this in order to plot the orange lines?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

That is because the character `'o'` is not a [pre-defined single-letter color code](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/color/named_colors.html). You will instead need to use either the RGB value or the string `'orange'` as your color specification (see below).

```
plt.plot(x, z3, '--', color='orange')           % String colorspec
plt.plot(x, z3, '--', color='#FFA500')          % Hex colorspec
plt.plot(x, z3, '--', color=[1.0, 0.5, 0.25])   % RGB colorspec
```

Answer (score 4):

`"o"` is not one of the available color codes.

An alternative to `plt.plot(x,z3,'o--')` is, for example,

```
plt.plot(x, z3, '--', color="orange")
```

Answer (score 3):

Use HTML colour codes to specify the colour of your plot. Something along the lines of ->

```
plt.plot(x,y,'o',color='#F39C12')
```

This plots x,y with orange circles. 
[orange circles look pretty with sinusiods](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SSvnD.png)

Edit: You can nitpick your color at http://htmlcolorcodes.com/